# How do I find out my server's request IP using PHP

Tags: php, ip, file-get-contents

I'm trying to see what my server's request IP is. For example.

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents("https://example.com");
?>
```

I want to know what IP my server is using to connect to `example.com`. I cannot use tools like IPLookUp because that just gets the IP of the response and if I have cloudflare on my domain, then it will keep showing cloudflares proxy IP's.

---

If I use `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` it just shows me the local IP `127.0.0.7`

Answer (score 0):

Use [gethostbyname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php)

`gethostbyname ( string $hostname )`